# display:inline-block is breaking my centering mechanism - how to fix?

Tags: css

I want to use `display:inline-block` per this [SO Post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/make-div-width-equal-to-child-contents) so that a div will take the dimensions of its children.

It works as stated in the post.  The problem I'm having is that now my centering is broken by this change.

I was centering the div using

```
margin: 0px auto;
```

I want the div centered and I also want it to take the dimensions of it children.

Here is the CSS for the containing div:

```
#container-1{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

Here is the HTML - just two p tags in a div.

```
<div id="container-1">
    <p id='si_but' class='si_match blue_but radius_all medium_white'>SignIn</p>
    <p id='su_but' class='si_match orange_but radius_all medium_white'>SignUp</p>
</div>
```

and if needed the CSS for the 2 p tags:

```
.si_match{
  cursor:  pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding:  14px 14px;  
  text-decoration:  none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#si_but{
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  float: left;
}
#su_but{
  position: relative;
  right: 50px;
  float: right;
}
```

**Update:**
The larger concern is why is my containing div about 200 px to the left.  There is nothing indicating why this is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS center display inline block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980525/css-center-display-inline-block)

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to add a "text-align: center" to the parent element. So considering "< body >"to be its parent element.

```
body{
text-align: center;
}

#container-1{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

Here's the related HTML.

```
<body>
    <div id="container-1">
        <p id='si_but' class='si_match blue_but radius_all medium_white'>SignIn</p>
        <p id='su_but' class='si_match orange_but radius_all medium_white'>SignUp</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You could add text-align:center to the body element:

```
body{
   text-align:center;
}
```

Answer copied from here: [CSS center display inline block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980525/css-center-display-inline-block)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use display table instead of inline-block.

```
#container-1{
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`text-align:center` on the parent will center `inline-block` children.

Any misalignment is probaby related to the positioning you have applied. Just remove it along with the float.

```css
#container-1 {
  text-align: center;
}
.si_match {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 14px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="container-1">
  <p id='si_but' class='si_match blue_but radius_all medium_white'>SignIn</p>
  <p id='su_but' class='si_match orange_but radius_all medium_white'>SignUp</p>
</div>
```