# How to display figure elements inline in div

Tags: css, html, figure

I want to display `figure` elements (that has images) inline in a `div` element, but it should be max 3 images in a row, horizontally centered.

Like this:

|X_X_X|
|X_X_X|
|_X_X_|

This is a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNGyeq) example:

#### Snippet

```css
#out {
  width: 210px;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.pic {
  width: 70px;
}
.fig-pic {
  position: relative;
  width: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div id="out">
  <figure class="fig-pic">
    <img class="pic" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTYTf4zHVj4z_iuCqfmvaQQd-F2w1szPbM3w618ty1UyYdoIkdKcg">
  </figure>
  <figure class="fig-pic">
    <img class="pic" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTYTf4zHVj4z_iuCqfmvaQQd-F2w1szPbM3w618ty1UyYdoIkdKcg">
  </figure>
  <figure class="fig-pic">
    <img class="pic" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTYTf4zHVj4z_iuCqfmvaQQd-F2w1szPbM3w618ty1UyYdoIkdKcg">
  </figure>
  <figure class="fig-pic">
    <img class="pic" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTYTf4zHVj4z_iuCqfmvaQQd-F2w1szPbM3w618ty1UyYdoIkdKcg">
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put `inline-block` to the `.fig-pic` [so you can use `text-align` on them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980525/css-center-display-inline-block):

```css
#out{
  width: 210px;
  text-align: center;
}

.fig-pic{
  width: 70px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
}

img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="out">
  <figure class="fig-pic">
    <img class="pic" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTYTf4zHVj4z_iuCqfmvaQQd-F2w1szPbM3w618ty1UyYdoIkdKcg">
  </figure><!--
  --><figure class="fig-pic">
    <img class="pic" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTYTf4zHVj4z_iuCqfmvaQQd-F2w1szPbM3w618ty1UyYdoIkdKcg">
  </figure><!--
  --><figure class="fig-pic">
    <img class="pic" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTYTf4zHVj4z_iuCqfmvaQQd-F2w1szPbM3w618ty1UyYdoIkdKcg">
  </figure><!--
--><figure class="fig-pic">
    <img class="pic" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTYTf4zHVj4z_iuCqfmvaQQd-F2w1szPbM3w618ty1UyYdoIkdKcg">
  </figure><!--
--><figure class="fig-pic">
    <img class="pic" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTYTf4zHVj4z_iuCqfmvaQQd-F2w1szPbM3w618ty1UyYdoIkdKcg">
  </figure>
</div>
```

[However, watch out for the `inline-block` whitespace.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Also, **remove the `figure` default `margins`.**

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/65L2osLt/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: @Fale1994 you're welcome. Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `inline-block` and `width:33.3%` for `figure`, this way you will have 3 images per row and it will be responsive. Using `text-align:center` in the parent container will center the content whenever the content isn't enough to fit the whole `width` parent, such as your last row.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box /* apply box model ta all elements */
}
body {
  margin: 0; /* reset default margin for body */
}
#out {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0; /* fix inline-block gap */
  text-align: center; /* align content to center */
}
figure {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.3%; /* make images to fit 3 per row */
  padding: 5%; /* demo */
  margin: 0 /* reset default margin for figure */
}
img {
  max-width: 100% /* width won't have more than 100% of parent width */
}
```

```html
<div id="out">
  <figure class="fig-pic">
    <img class="pic" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTYTf4zHVj4z_iuCqfmvaQQd-F2w1szPbM3w618ty1UyYdoIkdKcg">
  </figure>
  <figure class="fig-pic">
    <img class="pic" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTYTf4zHVj4z_iuCqfmvaQQd-F2w1szPbM3w618ty1UyYdoIkdKcg">
  </figure>
  <figure class="fig-pic">
    <img class="pic" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTYTf4zHVj4z_iuCqfmvaQQd-F2w1szPbM3w618ty1UyYdoIkdKcg">
  </figure>
  <figure class="fig-pic">
    <img class="pic" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTYTf4zHVj4z_iuCqfmvaQQd-F2w1szPbM3w618ty1UyYdoIkdKcg">
  </figure>
  <figure class="fig-pic">
    <img class="pic" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTYTf4zHVj4z_iuCqfmvaQQd-F2w1szPbM3w618ty1UyYdoIkdKcg">
  </figure>
  <figure class="fig-pic">
    <img class="pic" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTYTf4zHVj4z_iuCqfmvaQQd-F2w1szPbM3w618ty1UyYdoIkdKcg">
  </figure>
  <figure class="fig-pic">
    <img class="pic" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTYTf4zHVj4z_iuCqfmvaQQd-F2w1szPbM3w618ty1UyYdoIkdKcg">
  </figure>
  <figure class="fig-pic">
    <img class="pic" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTYTf4zHVj4z_iuCqfmvaQQd-F2w1szPbM3w618ty1UyYdoIkdKcg">
  </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your own example;

Your fig-pic div's need

```
.fig-pic
{
  inline-block
  margin:0;
}
```

to align alongside eachtoher. Since there's always a little room between inline-block elements, you should eliminate that space by setting

```
#out
{
  font-size:0 
}
```

or make your #out div a little wider.
To center use:

```
#out
{
  text-align: center;
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mPrvmY)