# Aligning a div to the center with display: inline-block

Tags: html, css

I have a `div`  with the style `display: inline-block` - this is used to make the div automatically expand to it's content.

The `div` won't center using `margin: 0 auto;`. To troubleshoot this, I changed the element's style to `display: block` and `width: 100px` and it does center.

How am I able to center the `div` element which uses `display: inline-block`?

```css
ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin: 0 auto; display: inline-block;">
<ul>
<li>Example</li>
<li>Example</li>
<li>Example</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8xz0sze6/2/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS center display inline block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980525/css-center-display-inline-block) / https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inline+block+center

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `body {text-align:center;}` to make the div centered on the page.

Or you can wrap this div in another div with a width of 100% and text-align center.

Comment: Thanks for this, Rachel - it didn't appear to be this simple when I was searching around as all the answers seem to be long and complex _(we need more simple answers like yours!)_. Thanks again :)

Comment: My pleasure. I'm glad to have learned something new today because of your question :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about horizontal alignment. Then you need the parent container to have text-align:center (and proper width) for the auto margin trick to work:

```
<div style="text-align:center;width:100%">
  <div style="margin: 0 auto; display: inline-block;">
    <ul>
      <li>Example</li>
      <li>Example</li>
      <li>Example</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6ygqqko3/

Answer (score 0):

something like that?

```
<div class="center" style="margin: 0 auto; display: inline-block;text-align:center;">
<ul>
<li>Example</li>
<li>Example</li>
<li>Example</li>
</ul>
</div>

ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
ul li {
    display: inline;
}
.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DlanorJQ/x0mx6efz/