# Odoo display data on report

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

How display data in one or two row?

Source line:

```
<div t-field="doc.partner_invoice_id"
                        t-field-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name", "phone", "fax"], "no_marker": true, "phone_icons": true}'/>
```

return:

ADDRESS 
NAME 
PHONE 
FAX

I want **ADDRESS, NAME, PHONE, FAX**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS center display inline block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980525/css-center-display-inline-block)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `span` to print them on the same line:

```
<div>
    <span t-field="o.partner_id.street"/>
    <span t-field="o.partner_id.name"/>
    <span t-field="o.partner_id.phone"/>
    <span t-field="o.partner_id.fax"/>
</div>
```