# How to center an display:inline-block section

Tags: html, css

Note: Not duplicate of [CSS center display inline block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980525/css-center-display-inline-block)

This is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gamh26o/244/):

```css
body {
  max-width:400px;
}

.scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.card {
display:inline-block;
width:240px;
 list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<section class="scroll">
      <ol>
       <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg" />
     
     </a>
     
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
     
    </li>
  
    
    <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg"/>
     
     </a>
     
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
     
    </li>
    
    <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg"/>
     
     </a>
     
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
     
    </li>
    
    <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg"/>
     
     </a>
     
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
     
    </li>
    
    <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg"/>
     
     </a>
     
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
     
    </li>
  
 
         </ol>
 
 
 </section>
  
  
  </div>
```

I tried `display:block;margin:auto` in outer div.
I tried `position:relative;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%)`

I tried `text-align:center;`

But nothing seems to work. Is it even possible?

Thanks in advance guys :)

Comment: do you want a vertical align or a horizontal align?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? pls explain briefly.

Comment: Firstly, there is not a single div in your code, let alone an outer div. Secondly, what needs to be centered?

Comment: you do realize that you have `max-width: 400px` on `body`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try , `justify-content : center;` or `align-items: center;` it will bring your content center

if you want to bring your text center , use `text-align:center` in your `.scroll` class

```css
body {
  max-width:400px;
}

.scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}
.card {
display:inline-block;
align-items: center;
width:240px;
 list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<section class="scroll">
      <ol>
       <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg" />
     
     </a>
     
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
     
    </li>
  
    
    <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg"/>
     
     </a>
     
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
     
    </li>
    
    <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg"/>
     
     </a>
     
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
     
    </li>
    
    <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg"/>
     
     </a>
     
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
     
    </li>
    
    <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg"/>
     
     </a>
     
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
     
    </li>
  
 
         </ol>
 
 
 </section>
  
  
  </div>
```

Comment: Oh, But there is no text in scroll class. Why it works?

Comment: scroll was presented as root class for entire div. text-align center will work on text. thats why it works. if you added any text inside it will apply the same on it

Answer (score 0):

> `.card`s are chidrens `scroll` and them have `display:inline-block;` so better way is use of `text-align` property.Like this:

```
.scroll {
  text-align:center;
  //More Code...
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gamh26o/246/)

Comment: Oh, But there is no text in scroll class. Why it works?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following code to your CSS.

```
ol {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

That will get rid of the space on the left hand side, which belongs to the `ol` and not any of the `li` elements.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lst5c9w/)

```css
body {
  max-width:400px;
}

.scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ol {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.card {
display:inline-block;
width:240px;
 list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<section class="scroll">
      <ol>
       <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg" />
     </a>
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg"/>
     </a>
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg"/>
     </a>
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg"/>
     </a>
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
    </li>
    <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg"/>
     </a>
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
    </li>
         </ol>
 </section>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You set entire body of the html to max-width:400px so you cannot positioning child elements. If you want to align remove max-width property of body class

**Remove**

```
body {
max-width:400px;
}
```

**To Change**

```
 body {

}
```

And then set align to child elements

Try this

```css
body {
  
}

.scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align:center;
  max-width:400px;
  margin:auto;
}
.card {
display:inline-block;
width:240px;
 list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<section class="scroll">
      <ol>
       <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg" />
     
     </a>
     
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
     
    </li>
  
    
    <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg"/>
     
     </a>
     
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
     
    </li>
    
    <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg"/>
     
     </a>
     
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
     
    </li>
    
    <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg"/>
     
     </a>
     
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
     
    </li>
    
    <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg"/>
     
     </a>
     
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
     
    </li>
  
 
         </ol>
 
 
 </section>
  
  
  </div>
```

Otherwise if you want to keep entire body max-width

Try this

```css
body {
max-width:400px;
margin:auto;

}

.scroll {
  
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  
}
.card {
display:inline-block;
width:240px;
 list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<section class="scroll">
      <ol>
       <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg" />
     
     </a>
     
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
     
    </li>
  
    
    <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg"/>
     
     </a>
     
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
     
    </li>
    
    <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg"/>
     
     </a>
     
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
     
    </li>
    
    <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg"/>
     
     </a>
     
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
     
    </li>
    
    <li class="card">
        <a href="#">
     
     <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w240_and_h266_bestv2/jYohlUVkLPFdnDryZ8V1HZkJzDt.jpg"/>
     
     </a>
     
     <p class="castname"><a href="#">Aamir Khan</a></p>
     
    </li>
  
 
         </ol>
 
 
 </section>
  
  
  </div>
```